# Update a value in the object in an Array in react in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-state-management

I am dispatching an action that will update the values in the redux state and I am passing an array. But before that, I want to update the array by changing the object values but I keep getting an error -
Cannot assign to read only property 'position' of object

I am not sure why I am getting this error because I am creating a new Array and updating the values in that.

Code

```
export const GetCustomers= (customers) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  let activeCustomers = Array.from(customers);
  for (let i = 0; i < activeCustomers.length; i += 1) {
     activeCustomers[i].position = i;
  }

  dispatch(actions.updateActiveCustomers(activeCustomers));
  );
};
```

Getting an error -
Cannot assign to read only property 'position' of object

I am not sure why I am getting this error because I am creating a new Array and updating the values in that.

Comment: `Array.from` only makes a shallow copy, so `activeCustomers[i]` is the same as `customers[i]`

Comment: What happens when you log activeCustomers after Array.from .. ?

Comment: @RobinZigmond How do I make it a deepCopy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deep copy use:

```
  let activeCustomers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(customers));
```